# Login with facebook opening in other language

Tags: jquery, facebook

My website has feature to login with facebook. I created app as well and its working fine. Problem is when user press login with facebook, its opening facebook in indian language. It should be english, Any settings in app for that? Here is my code for sample:

```
FB.login(function(response) {

    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        getData( $button );
    }
    else{

    }
}, {scope: 'public_profile,email'});
```

Any suggesstions?

Comment: The language a site is displayed in is controlled by the `accept-language` header sent in the requests. This will be set in the browser settings. If you're seeing the site in Indian, then your culture will be set to `in`, or some derivative of it. To fix this just change the setting in your browser.

Comment: Its on my website. How can I control client's browser settings. is there any way to send language parameter?